# Androidアプリで実施しているHTTPリクエストの中身を見る方法

Tags: android

WebクライアントアプリでREST APIを実施している場合、
ブラウザのデベロッパーツールなどで、HTTPリクエストの中身が確認できるかと思います。

AndroidアプリでREST APIを実施している場合、
アプリ内にログを埋め込むような方法ではなく、
同じようにHTTPリクエストの中身を見る方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

Android において

> ブラウザのデベロッパーツールなど

に匹敵するものは、Android Studio になりますが、その場合は、[Network Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler?hl=ja) を使う形になると思います。

[image: Network Inspector]

Comment: これです！もともと、Android StudioのProfilerだかにメモリ、CPUなどと一緒にあった気がしてたのですが、なくなっていたので…ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 通信なら、Wi-Fi でネットワークに接続した Android スマホの HTTP 通信を、同じ LAN 内の PC にインストールした Fiddler Classic (Windows 専用の無償版) でキャプチャすることはできます。詳しくは [Android の HTTP 通信を Fiddler でキャプチャ](http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2022/07/01/how-to-use-fiddler-to-capture-android-http-communications.aspx) を見てください。

HTTPS 通信は、紹介した記事にも書きましたが、証明書をダウンロードして、Android にインストールすればキャプチャできるようになるはずですが未検証です。

Comment: このようなアプリケーションがあるのですね！もしかして、これならデバッグ版でなくともキャプチャ見れたりするのかも…と期待して、使用してみたいと思います。